# pyqtgraph's exporter shifts plot components

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have a sample code that produces a standard scatterplot with pairs of X & Y. For the project I'm working on, we cannot use matplotlib, but stick to pyqtgraph instead (it is part of a PyQt project).

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=100)
y = np.random.normal(size=100)

app = QtGui.QApplication([]) # create the application
w = QtGui.QWidget() 
pwidget = pg.PlotWidget()

pwidget.addLegend(size=(100, 10)) # add a legend

pwidget.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol="o", name="My Data") # plot the data

line = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=45, movable=False) # add a line through origin
pwidget.addItem(line)

pwidget.setXRange(-3, 3)
pwidget.setYRange(-3, 3)

layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(pwidget)
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Now this code works just fine and does, what it should do. This is a screenshot of the popup window:
[image: Scatterplot as it should be]

When trying to export like this, however:

```
exporter = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(pwidget.plotItem)
exporter.export('D:/file_example.png')
```

I get the following error:

> File
>   "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\exporters\ImageExporter.py",
>   line 70, in export
>       bg = np.empty((self.params['width'], self.params['height'], 4), dtype=np.ubyte) TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an
>   index

[Dr. Google](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/538) showed me that this may be a bug of the version I (have to) use and that there is the workaround of setting width and height manually. So I updated the code like this:

```
exporter = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(pwidget.plotItem)
exporter.params.param('width').setValue(1024, blockSignal=exporter.widthChanged)
exporter.params.param('height').setValue(860, blockSignal=exporter.heightChanged)
exporter.export('D:/file_example.png')
```

with the following rather disturbing result:

[image: Shifted result, components are "off track"]

I played around with the `exporter.params`, but nothing changed the result.
Any ideas are highly appreciated, thanks!